# CSS javascript animation

Tags: javascript, css

I cannot actually do the animation thing. I tried to call the function but it is not working. As a self-learner, i couldn't ask anyone. So, yes. Pretty noob but couldn't find the answer anywhere on web.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>

<p><button onclick="main()">Click Me</button></p> 

<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>

function main() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
    var posTop = elem.style.top;
    var posLeft = elem.style.left;
    function realAnimate(posTop,posLeft){
        if (posTop<350){
            for (let index = 0; index < posTop; index++) {
                return posTop;
                posTop == posLeft;
                return posLeft;
                realAnimate(posTop,posLeft);
            }
            
        }
        else{
            for (let index = 0; index > posTop; index--) {
                return posTop;
                posTop == posLeft;
                return posLeft;
                realAnimate(posTop,posLeft);
            }
        }
    }
}
window.setInterval(main,0)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting to animate to and from the edges, that the cube has to travel.

Comment: why not trying with a CSS animation? it's much more easy

Comment: Your code reveals major misunderstandings regarding general concepts of JavaScript, some of which being: **a)** `return` returns a value and exits current execution (therefore none of the code after it is ever run) - your `for`s are always exiting in the first iteration, both of them returning `posTop`, which is empty string `''`; **b)** `a == b` is not an assignment, it's an evaluation which returns true if `a` is loosely equal to `b` and false otherwise. The best advice I could give you is to take a working example and change it slightly and learn from what the change does.

Answer (score 0):

just give a inline top and left style to the element so that the DOM will recognize any values. Because if you dont . The value for your element will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function main(){
  $('.animate').toggleClass('move');
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
.animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:all 5s linear;
}
.move{
  top:350px;
  left:350px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button onclick="main()">Click Me</button></p> 

<div id ="container">
  <div class ="animate"></div>
</div>
```